# Hacer programa en MIPS 32 sin instrucciones lógicas, con lw, lb, lbu, sw, sb

Tags: ensamblador, mips32

Tengo este código en MIPS 32. Estoy intentando hacerlo solo con estas instrucciones: lw, lb, lbu, sw, sb, sin usar instrucciones lógicas.

Este es el código que tengo y funciona, pero lo quiero hacer sin las instrucciones lógicas.

```
.data
palabra_original: .word 0x10203040       # Palabra original almacenada en cierta posición
palabra_reorganizada: .space 4            # Espacio para la palabra reorganizada
Extraer_bytes: .word 0xFF                       # Sirve para extraer un byte
```

.text
.globl main

main:
# Cargar la palabra original
lw $t0, palabra_original         # Carga la palabra original en $t0

```
# Extraer y reorganizar los bytes
andi $t1, $t0, 0xFF             # Obtiene el byte menos significativo
sll $t1, $t1, 24               # Desplaza a la posición más significativa
andi $t2, $t0, 0xFF00           # Obtiene el segundo byte
sll $t2, $t2, 8                # Desplaza a la posición del segundo byte
or $t1, $t1, $t2               # Combina el primer y segundo byte
andi $t2, $t0, 0xFF0000         # Obtiene el tercer byte
srl $t2, $t2, 8                # Desplaza a la posición del tercer byte
or $t1, $t1, $t2               # Combina con los bytes anteriores
andi $t2, $t0, 0xFF000000       # Obtiene el byte más significativo
srl $t2, $t2, 24               # Desplaza a la posición menos significativa
or $t1, $t1, $t2               # Combina con los bytes anteriores

# Almacena la palabra reorganizada
sw $t1, palabra_reorganizada  # Almacenar la palabra reorganizada

# Termina el programa
# Salida del programa
li $v0, 10                     # Carga el código de salida de la syscall (10 para salir)
syscall                        # Realiza la syscall para salir del programa
```

Y esta es la versión que estoy intentando sin ellas; me genera error, además no da el resultado esperado el cual es invertir el orden de los bytes en esta palabra: 0x10203040.